Powerbi "paginated report" access from Flask API, Not Found error 404. How can I solve this problem?
I have a problem with to trying access a "paginated report" from powerbi through the Flask API to show it, and when trying to access the "paginated report" I get the error (404 Not Found), but that "paginated report" exists and I can access it from powerbi.
I can access to "reports" without problem from the Flask API, but not with the "paginated reports".
"paginated report" permissions are the same as "report", I think.
I shared my code with you
def generate_powbi3(group_id, report_id, access_token_ms):

    # para obtener el enlace embebido y la info del reporte
    cabecera = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token_ms}
    report_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/rdlreports/{report_id}' 
    api_response = requests.get(report_url, headers=cabecera)
    
    if api_response.status_code != 200:    
        print('')
        print(report_url)    
        print_error(f'Error 1 while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nStatus Code:\t{api_response.status_code}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')
        abort(api_response.status_code, description=f'Error 1 while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nStatus Code:\t{api_response.status_code}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')

    embed_url = api_response.json().get('embedUrl')# enlace embebido

    print('')
    print('')
    print('API.POWERBI.COM')
    print(api_response.json())
    print('')
    print('')
    # return api_response.json()
    
    api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
    report = ReportConfig(api_response['id'], api_response['name'], api_response['embedUrl'])

    request_body = EmbedTokenRequestBody()
    if 'datasetId' in api_response.keys():
        dataset_ids = [api_response['datasetId']]
        for dataset_id in dataset_ids:
            request_body.datasets.append({'id': dataset_id})

    request_body.reports.append({'id': report_id})
    request_body.targetWorkspaces.append({'id': group_id})

    # Generate Embed token for multiple workspaces, datasets, and reports. Refer https://aka.ms/MultiResourceEmbedToken
    embed_token_api = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/rdlreports/{report_id}/GenerateToken'
    api_response_token = requests.post(embed_token_api, data=json.dumps(request_body.__dict__), headers=cabecera)

    if api_response_token.status_code != 200:
        abort(api_response_token.status_code, description=f'Error 2 while retrieving Embed token\n{api_response_token.reason}:\t{api_response_token.text}\nStatus Code:\t{api_response_token.status_code}\nRequestId:\t{api_response_token.headers.get("RequestId")}')
    
    print('GenerateToken')
    print(api_response_token.json())
    print('')
    print('')
    # embed_token = self.get_embed_token_for_single_report_single_workspace(report_id, dataset_ids, workspace_id)
    # embed_config = EmbedConfig(embed_token.tokenId, embed_token.token, embed_token.tokenExpiry, [report.__dict__])
    access_token_powerbi = api_response_token.json().get('token')# extrae el token embebido
    if(not embed_url):# si no existe aun el enlace lo crea
        embed_url = f'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId={report_id}&groupId={group_id}&autoAuth=true&ctid={access_token_powerbi}'
    return embed_url, access_token_powerbi, report_id

@app.route('/dec_anual_op_mod_347')
@jwt_required()
def dec_anual_op_mod_347():

    user_id = get_jwt_identity()  # Obtiene el ID del usuario del token JWT

    if(user_id):# si tiene id de usuario
        roles_user = extractRoles(user_id, db['users'])

        if not checkPermissions(roles_user, db, 'access_imd'):
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

        list_submenus_navbar = checkPermissionsNavbar(roles_user, db, 'imd')

        # ID del grupo de trabajo (espacio de trabajo) y del informe
        group_id = "<id>"
        report_id = "<group>"
        
        access_token_ms = request.cookies.get('access_token_ms', None)# obtiene el token de microsoft
        if(not access_token_ms):
            return render_template('powerbi.html', list_submenus_navbar=list_submenus_navbar, tipo='dec_anual_op_mod_347', embed_url=None, access_token = None, report_id=None, message_error=translate('error_token_ms'), title_error=translate('error_token_ms_title'))
        
        embed_token = generate_powbi3(group_id, report_id, access_token_ms)
        
        return render_template('powerbi.html', list_submenus_navbar=list_submenus_navbar, tipo='dec_anual_op_mod_347', embed_token=embed_token, report_id=report_id, group_id=group_id)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

The problem is when I make a request for the url:
'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/rdlreports/{report_id}'
This response is status code 404 Not Found.
How can I solve this problem?
these are the permissions granted:
enter image description here
enter image description here
And the SCOPE is this:
SCOPE = ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default']
And the relationship that "paginated report" has with the database is this:
enter image description here
Has anyone had the same problem?
Is there something I missed? Or do you have to do something different for that type of reports?

Do you have any solution for this? I am in same trouble too.

The solution to this problem is to change the role of any user so that they apply changes.
